# How do I remove a column default in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do I write a migration in Ecto to remove a column's default value? Let's say I have a table called `:users` with a column called `:timezone` that previously had defaulted to "Etc/UTC"...

Here's the start of my migration...

```
  def up do
    alter table(:users) do
      modify :timezone, :string, default: fragment("NULL"), null: true
    end
  end
  def down do
    alter table(:users) do
      modify :timezone, :string, default: "Etc/UTC", null: false
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think you need to do `default: nil`. Can you see if it works?

Comment: I just checked. `default: nil` will set the default no `NULL`. It won't exactly "DROP" the default (like you'd get with `ALTER COLUMN "timezone" DROP DEFAULT`). I didn't find any mention of "DROP DEFAULT" in Ecto so I believe this is not possible right now.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-default.html

> If no default value is declared explicitly, the default value is the null value.

So @Dogbert is correct, `default: nil` is the way to go.

If you really want to, you could directly write the SQL command `ALTER COLUMN "timezone" DROP DEFAULT` using [`execute/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#execute/1).

Comment: That creates a default of `NULL::character varying`, not the same as dropping the default.